# Iphone App Testing Error - STComposeString & SenTestCase Error

Tags: iphone, xcode, testing, error-handling

I'm having a problem with building my iPhone app..so, i finally finished it, but now when i try to test or profile my app , a error shows up..

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_STComposeString", referenced from:
      -[TaxiApp_Tests testExample] in TaxiApp_Tests.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SenTestCase", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_TaxiApp_Tests in TaxiApp_Tests.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_SenTestCase", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_TaxiApp_Tests in TaxiApp_Tests.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: duplicate of this question --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9614313/xcode-4-3-build-error-missing-required-architecture-armv7/9614639#9614639

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you running it in the simulator? Based on the answer here:

[XCode 4.3 - Build error "missing required architecture armv7"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9614313/xcode-4-3-build-error-missing-required-architecture-armv7)

your testing framework will not run properly on the iphone.

Comment: I am testing on my iPhone .. is there any difference ?

Comment: Yes, as I said, your testing framework will not run on the iphone, see the linked answer.

Comment: should i try with this one ? Select Project in project navigator
Select Test Target
Select Build Settings
Go down to Framework Search Paths and single-click it
Delete whatever is there
Enter $(SDKROOT)/Developer/Library/Frameworks $(DEVELOPER_LIBRARY_DIR)/Frameworks
If you had any custom frameworks, add those back

Comment: No, it looks that as long as you're using the SenTestingKit, you won't be able to run on the iPhone.

Comment: ooo...it works now when i deleted the SenTesting Framework and some lines in App_Tests.h and .m .. but won't that effect to my app ? in the way that something more worst appears ?