# GHUnit error file _OBJC_CLASS_$_SenTestCase", referenced

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, ocunit, gh-unit

I'm using GHUnit in my project but when i try to run the app it gives errors

> Ld /Users/goldfire/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WhatsMySpeed-amkgqintxyhelabqvrpouivmdglf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GHUnitTests.app/GHUnitTests normal i386
>       cd /Users/goldfire/Desktop/Example/WhatsMySpeed
>       setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
>       setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk -L/Users/goldfire/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WhatsMySpeed-amkgqintxyhelabqvrpouivmdglf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/goldfire/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WhatsMySpeed-amkgqintxyhelabqvrpouivmdglf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/goldfire/Desktop/Example/WhatsMySpeed -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks -filelist /Users/goldfire/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WhatsMySpeed-amkgqintxyhelabqvrpouivmdglf/Build/Intermediates/WhatsMySpeed.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GHUnitTests.build/Objects-normal/i386/GHUnitTests.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -ObjC -all_load -fobjc-arc -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=50100 -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -framework GHUnitIOS -framework SenTestingKit -o /Users/goldfire/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WhatsMySpeed-amkgqintxyhelabqvrpouivmdglf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GHUnitTests.app/GHUnitTests
>
> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SenTestCase", referenced from:
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_LogicTests in LogicTests.o
>     "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_SenTestCase", referenced from:
>         _OBJC_METACLASS_$_LogicTests in LogicTests.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Refer this link which has your answer.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9614313/xcode-4-3-build-error-missing-required-architecture-armv7

Answer (score 7):

Check out this link:
http://fstanley.github.com/blog/2012/06/10/fixing-ghunit-sentestcase-link-errors/

Basically you need to add:

`$(SDKROOT)/Developer/Library/Frameworks`

and

`$(DEVELOPER_LIBRARY_DIR)/Frameworks`

to the framework search paths in the settings for your test target.

I had the same error and this fixed it.

Note: that the items must be added in that exact order, per http://forum.sparrow-framework.org/topic/cant-run-unit-tests.