# GHUnit error _OBJC_CLASS_$_SenTestCase", referenced

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, gh-unit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [GHUnit error file _OBJC_CLASS_$_SenTestCase", referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10651662/ghunit-error-file-objc-class-sentestcase-referenced)

I would like to use GHUnit in my project but i'm getting this error

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SenTestCase", referenced from:
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_LogicTests in LogicTests.o
>     "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_SenTestCase", referenced from:
>         _OBJC_METACLASS_$_LogicTests in LogicTests.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 2):

Be sure you linked `SenTestingKit.framework` with your project (although, with GHUnit it really shouldn't be necessary).

Comment: yes i turned on the target GHUnitTests on SenTestingKit.framework